# Javascript closure doesn't capture var variables

Tags: javascript

```js
(function() {
  var debounce = function(func, delay) {
    var inDebounce;
    return function() {
      var context = this;
      var args = arguments;
      clearTimeout(inDebounce);
      inDebounce = setTimeout(function() {
        func.apply(context, args);
      }, delay);
    }
  }
  var scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  var quarterHeight = scrollHeight / 4;
  var quarters = 0;
  var scrollDistance, divisible, percent;
  document.addEventListener("scroll", debounce(function() {
    scrollDistance = window.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    divisible = Math.trunc(scrollDistance / quarterHeight);
    if (quarters < divisible) {
      scrollPercent = divisible * 25;
      heap.track('Scroll Depth', {
        percent: scrollPercent
      });
      quarters++;
    }
  }, 100));
}());
```

Inside the event listender, scrollHeight is always 0 when I do a console print out. Why is that? I tested it in Chrome. It's as if the closure is not capturing scrollHeight.

When I move the line inside the closure, it works.

Comment: You don't use `scrollHeight` inside the event listener.

Comment: You only set `scrollHeight` once

Comment: Your main document may be scaled 100%, try selecting body or a div inside that for scroll height.

Comment: When you set a variable to an expression, it doesn't re-evaluate the expression each time you use it, it just captures the value at the time of the assignment. So `scrollHeight` won't change automatically when `document.documentElement.scrollHeight` or `window.innerHeight` changes. That's why you have to put the assignment into the function.